# c# Call a method every x seconds but only a certain amount of times

Tags: c#, console, timing

Im looking to call the same method every x seconds in my c# console app, but I also want to only call this method a certain number of times (say 5).
I need each method to run after each other (cant have them over lapping)
My biggest issue is the console app closing before being completed

The current code I have works but is kinda messy (the while loop)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
            {
                InitTimer(t);
            }
        }

        public static void InitTimer(int t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Init" + t);
            int x = 0;
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => x = MyMethod(x),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            //delay between seconds
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            //number of times called
            while (x < 5)
            {
            }
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        public static int MyMethod(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test" + x);
            //call post method
            x += 1;
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Is there a neater way to create the same functionality ?

Comment: Turn timer off when you reach 5.

Comment: How do you want this to function if a method call takes longer then x seconds? do you want the next call to fire right away? And if so is the timer reset to 5 seconds again or will it try to make up for lost time?